# Foreign key disappears when I do reverse engineering using mysql workbench 

Tags: mysql, reverse-engineering

When I use mysql workbench, the schema of reverse engineering disappears.

I don't know why.

Do you have solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reverse-engineering a MyISAM database you won't get foreign keys since they aren't supported by the engine. You must switch to InnoDB.